# Python trap routine

Tags: python, events, event-handling

Alright so for a living I program [ABB industrial robots](https://new.abb.com/products/robotics), and the programming language we use is called [Rapid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAPID).

One really cool thing I can do in Rapid is called a trap routine. And it's like a while loop but instead of looping through the whole loop before it checks a condition it will break literally as soon as the event its waiting for happens.

I suppose it is similar to an event listener in javascript. It's like it runs in the background of the normal program. I want to do this in python.

I have little formal CS education so I'm not exactly sure what this concept is. Sorry if it's a bit vague I'm not really sure how to ask it in a clear way.

Comment: Would it check the condition after each statement, or even while a statement is being executed?

Comment: It would check after each statement. As an example while the robot was executing a function if it lost a signal or something from a machine it was communicating with it would immediately execute another function I had told it to use in case that certain event happened.

Comment: Take a look at how Python handles [signals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html), with example e.g. [here](https://pymotw.com/3/signal/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most languages, so does Python handle [system signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) by using handler functions. For more details, take a look at the [Signals chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) which talks about receiving and sending signals, with examples e.g. [here](https://pymotw.com/3/signal/).

In short, you can bind a function to one or more signals:

```
>>> import signal
>>> import sys
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> # Here we define a function that we want to get called.
>>> def received_ctrl_c(signum, stack):
...     print("Received Ctrl-C")
...     sys.exit(0)
... 
>>> # Bind the function to the standard system Ctrl-C signal.
>>> handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, received_ctrl_c)
>>> handler
<built-in function default_int_handler>
>>> 
>>> # Now let’s loop forever, and break out only by pressing Ctrl-C, i.e. sending the SIGINT signal to the Python process.
>>> while True:
...     print("Waiting…")
...     time.sleep(5)
... 
Waiting…
Waiting…
Waiting…
^CReceived Ctrl-C
```

In your specific case, find out which signal(s) the robot sends to your Python process (or whichever process listens to signals) and then act on them as shown above.

Comment: Yes this seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Please add beef to your answer @Jens ; as it stands, it qualifies as a comment. For instance linking to an outside code resource is brittle as the link may become obsolete; it is recommended to copy and paste examples in your answer; thank you.

Comment: What they said. Links that support an answer are great, but the answer needs to have useful on-site content too. Of course, the official docs link is fairly resistant to link rot, and pymotw should be ok too, but please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Ok, I “beefed up” the answer… better? ☺️

Comment: Yes this worked thank you. Although this wasn't for the robots this was for personal use. Thank you though!