# How to call a function in python script before it exits when terminated with kill command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script called `flashscore.py`.

I need to kill the script in middle of execution. I am killing the process using the binary `kill`.

```sh
# Find process ID
$ pgrep -f flashscore.py
  55033

$ kill 55033
```

This script is run with `cronjob`. It launches headless chrome browser with `selenium` and does some other intermediary writes, so I want to clean up everything before script exits with a function like:

```py
def exit_gracefully():
    # kill chromedriver
    # flush other intermediate files
    pass
```

How do I achieve this if this is possible?

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269334/python-trap-routine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `kill` on unix should send a SIGTERM, which can be handled with the `signal` module. Something like:

```
import signal
import time
import sys

def handler(signum, frame):
    print("In SIGTERM handler")
    print("exiting gracefully")
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)


i = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(i, end='\r')
    i += 1
```

Comment: Cool. But how do you send parameters to handler when it gets called?

Comment: You can't. The interface the hander is fixed; it only receives the signal number and the stack frame. If you need more specialization, you need to use global variables.